# PHP in Azure cloud service

Tags: php, azure, cloud

Can any one suggest what is the configuration need to be done to run a simple php file in the Azure cloud service.

I am able to view my simple php file in Azure Web Site, But i cant view the same file in Azure Cloud service.

Can some one provide me some suggestions?

Comment: have at least opened this page: https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/php/ and downloaded the Windows Azure SDK for PHP? It comes with a bunch of command line tools that will pack your php WebRole into a Cloud Service package for use in Cloud Services.

Comment: Currently, using PowerShell cmdlets is the easiest way to go (which means you need to be on Windows). Details are here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/silverlining/archive/2012/06/21/creating-a-php-web-role-in-windows-azure.aspx

Answer (score -1):

When you say "I am able to view my simple php file in Azure Web Site, But i cant view the same file in Azure Cloud service.", I believe you mean you can browse your PHP site in Windows Azure Websites however not with Windows Azure Service configured as something.cloudapp.net. Isn't it?

As you asked for suggestions here are some steps you can use to troubleshoot your problem:

1. When you access your PHP file i.e. servicename.cloudapp.net/phpinfo.php does it shows file not found error or it returns error related with PHP runtime? This is because you would need to put together PHP runtime as well as all the PHP files in your package before deploying it. If you miss any of important content, your site will not run. So you must be sure that all the contents specific to your application are in your Package which you deployed to Windows Azure cloud service.
2. To verify you have all the contents in your Package, you can rename cspkg to zip and then unzip it. After that you can rename cssx file to zip again and unzip it to see if all the contents are there.
3. You can enabled RDP access to your Azure VM and log into to check for consistency

Also for Azure Cloud Service you use this documentation: http://azurephp.interoperabilitybridges.com/articles/packaging-applications

Comment: your link is deprecated. Since June 2012, the packaging PHP binaries are not compatible with the new version of the SDK azure.